# On update cascade not working with engine innodb

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I created 2 test tables trying to link 2 columns. Code:

```
create table test (
    id int primary key auto_increment
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table test2(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    id2 int not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES test(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then I insert 2 rows in the tables:

```
insert into test (id) values(1);
insert into test2 (id,id2) values(1,1);
```

Later I'm trying to update a row from table 'test' and supposedly it's should update a row in table 'test2' but it doesn't.

```
UPDATE test SET id=2 WHERE id=1;
SELECT * FROM test2;
```

Query result:

```
+----+-----+
| id | id2 |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  1  |
+----+-----+
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It should work just fine. Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2ca8/1) demo

Comment: @peterm it's should, but it doesn't... :( This make my crazy...

Comment: First of all you don't need to set a value to autoincremented field

Comment: It does not affect on foreign keys.

Comment: @DmitriKadykov take a look on fiddle witch posted @ peterm

Comment: What happens if you execute this SQL statement: `insert into test2 (id2) values (42);`?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' i tried and this query doesn't catch any error. It's strangely.

Comment: @IgorPatychenko: You might have disabled foreign key checks. Execute this, then start over: `set foreign_key_checks = 1;`. If that works, I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' it doesn't work. I run this query and it make the same think. http://prntscr.com/5lyjkj

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' MySQL Version 5.1.58
If you can advise me some free hosting with support php 5.4 and mysql where I will not have such problems with the database, I would be very grateful to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you describe is consistent with having foreign key checks disabled in MySQL. It might also be consistent with using an unsupported, disabled, or misspelled storage engine. To check the storage engines, use . . .

```
show engines;
```

. . . and read the information for the InnoDB engine. If you misspell the storage engine's name, MySQL will use the default instead. The default storage engine for your version, 5.1.xx, is MyISAM. MyISAM doesn't enforce foreign key constraints.

To see the current setting for foreign key checks, use . . .

```
select @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
```

To demonstrate the behavior you're seeing . . .

```
create table test (
    id int primary key auto_increment
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table test2(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    id2 int not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES test(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into test (id) values(1);
insert into test2 (id,id2) values(1,1);
```

Now let's turn off foreign key checks.

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;

UPDATE test SET id=2 WHERE id=1;
SELECT * FROM test2;
```

```
id   id2
--
1    1
```

No errors or warnings, but the update didn't cascade to "test2".

Now let's undo what we did . . .

```
UPDATE test SET id=1 WHERE id=2;
```

. . . enable foreign key checks, and run that update again.

```
set foreign_key_checks = 1;

UPDATE test SET id=2 WHERE id=1;
SELECT * FROM test2;
```

```
id   id2
--
1    2
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. You can see the end result of all commands in this screen-shot.

http://prntscr.com/5lz3b6

Comment: @IgorPatychenko: Updated answer with another possibility--storage engine.

Comment: It doesn't support InnoDB engine
http://prntscr.com/5lzdzu

Here's the thing. Thanks a lot.